# 1d.exe can't find SFML files?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I am trying to use SFML for the first time. I have installed everything correctly but I keep getting these same errors:

1d.exe: Cannot find -lsfml-window-s-d

I'm using Code::Blocks and it cannot find ANY of the files.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I recommend adding the linker command line to the question. The answers you seek will depend heavily on it.

Comment: How are we going to tell you how to fix it when you're not even saying what you have tried?

Comment: ***it cannot find ANY of the files*** By default on windows it should not find any of these files. You have to tell your compiler and your linker where you put them.

Comment: `1d.exe: Cannot find -lsfml-window-s-d` looks like some type of problem with the command line passed to the compiler or linker.

Comment: Did you consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your PC? On Debian, SFML works well.... And [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is a good C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy all files from "SFML/bin" to your project folder where main.cpp is.